# Controlling status bar in opencv image show

Tags: python, opencv, imageview

I'm using opencv with python 2.7. I have a question about image display.

When displaying an image in python/cv2, the status bar normally shows the pixel values when hovering with the cursor.
For example, the following code will display the below image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im=cv2.imread("Parrots.bmp")


cv2.namedWindow('img1' , cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("img1",im)

im_r=im[:,:,1]
#im_r=im_r.astype(float)/256 - uncommenting this line removes text from status bar
cv2.imshow("img2",im_r)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[parrot with status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mz5Fs.png)

You can see in the image that the status bar displays the pixel values. However, when displaying an image with floating numbers, the status bar display disappear.

Is there any way to control/customize the status bar display?

Comment: Not unless you want to modify the OpenCV sources. You could easily put together something similar that does what you want using, say, tkinter.